# How to write batch class for :Look for contacts whose Opportunity Created Date && (Task Creation Date OR Case Creation date) is more than X years

Tags: batch

My Batch class logic is:

```
global class batch_update_Daily_Contacts implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,schedulable
  
    {  
 
    Set<Id> ContactIds = New Set<Id>();
    set<Id> OppIds = New Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> CaseContactIds = New Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> WhoIds = New Set<Id>();
    List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
   
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {  
        string query = 'SELECT Id FROM Contact where Validate_Retention__c =false';
        if(query != null)
        {
            system.debug('inside if');
            return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
        }
        else
        return null;
    }
   
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Contact> scope)
    {
        for(Contact ConObj : Scope){
            ContactIds.add(ConObj.Id);
            system.debug('This is ContactIds: ' +ContactIds);
           
        }
        if(ContactIds != null){
            for(Case caseObj : [SELECT ID,ContactId FROM Case Where  (ContactId IN : ContactIds) OR (CreatedDate = TODAY)]){
                CaseContactIds.add(caseObj.ContactId);
                system.debug('This is CaseContactIds: ' +CaseContactIds);
             
            }
            for(Task taskObj : [SELECT ID,WhoID FROM Task Where ( WhoID IN : ContactIds AND Who.Type = 'Contact') Or (CreatedDate = TODAY) ])
            {
                WhoIds.add(taskObj.WhoID);
                system.debug('This is WhoIds: ' +WhoIds);
                
            }
             for(Opportunity oppObj : [select ContactId from Opportunity where Last_Donation__c = TODAY AND ContactId IN : ContactIds])
            {
                OppIds.add(oppObj.ContactID);
                system.debug('This is OppIds: ' +OppIds);
                
            }
        }
        if(CaseContactIds != null || WhoIds != null || OppIds != null){
            CaseContactIds.addAll(WhoIds);
            CaseContactIds.addAll(OppIds);
            system.debug('This is CaseContactIds: ' +CaseContactIds);
            
        }
        for(Contact ConObj : [SELECT ID FROM Contact WHERE ID IN : CaseContactIds]){
            system.debug('This is ConObj: ' +ConObj);
            ConObj.Validate_Retention__c = true;
            ConList.add(ConObj);
        }
        if(ConList != null){
            update ConList;
        }
     }
       
              global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
        {  
                
        }
   
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
        
    }
    }
```

After running, I am getting:

> "First error: Apex CPU time limit exceeded"

Can someone help here?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with this code that I don't think I can cover in a single answer, but I want to highlight a couple of specific points and then offer a general suggestion for what a good form of this code might look like.

#### Key Points

- Your logic in this code does not match your stated objective. There are no N-year mechanics here, and the queries that filter on Created Date appear to simply be wrong (they will include records unrelated to `scope`).
- The most likely source of the CPU time limit is that you're pulling in a very large number of irrelevant records to iterate over.
- You are performing a large number of `null` checks that are irrelevant because variables that you explicitly initialize will never be `null`.
- You should move your instance variables that are used only within `execute()` into the scope of that method. They are not functionally instance variables and this is likely to lead to confusion.
- Your batch class almost certainly should not be `global`.

#### Suggestions for Rebuilding

Your `execute()` method should not run queries against `Case`, `Opportunity`, and `Task`. Instead, you should run a query against `Contact` - against the `Contact` records that are in `scope` - to acquire details of these related objects through [parent-child subqueries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm), which return only the records related to each Contact. You can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses in your subqueries to get back, for example, only the most recent Opportunity for a given Contact.

Additionally, you may want to use the `LastActivityDate` field on Contact to avoid having to explicitly query the Task object.

For example, you might do something like

```
List<Contact> contactList = [
    SELECT Id, 
        (SELECT Id, Last_Donation__c FROM Opportunities ORDER BY Last_Donation__C DESC LIMIT 1), 
    // Add more subqueries here for Case and optionally Task
    FROM Contact
    WHERE Id IN :scope
]; 
for (Contact c : contactList) {
    if (c.Opportunities.size() > 0 && c.Opportunities.get(0).Last_Donation__c < SOME_DATE) {
         // Do action here. You'd need to also write logic on the other fields
         // and relationships that govern your action.
    }
}

update contactList;
```

This is a *very rough sketch*. Please do not copy and paste this code exactly as shown here; you'll need to do extensive work to incorporate your specific requirements and data model.